# Ant Design Cards doesn't align properly

Tags: html, reactjs, antd

I am tying to create a responsive design with cards. However, if the text inside the cards don't have equal sizes, cards wrap weirdly. What I am trying to achieve is having a 4 rows with 8 columns of cards with picture and text. I also tried using `List` but again if the size of text inside each card is not equal, cards don't separate equally.

[Code Pen Link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vqEwvM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick fix could be with CSS:

```
.ant-card-body{
  min-height: 80px;
  max-height: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use to display text :

```
   <Meta
      title="Card title"
      description="This is the description"
    />
```